# The authenticity of host “host” can't be established

Tags: linux, ssh, rsa, authorization

I'm running a web app on a Linux server which connects to other servers. When I run the project on my Play framework on loclhost it runs fluently. When I run it on my Linux server I get the above message 3 times, one for each server.

I read a post about it where it says that it is a man in the middle warning and if I write yes it should work. But though a write yes, nothing happens and the app doesn't run, and the error message keeps popping up.

I tried creating private and public keys and add them to the authorized_keys file, but it didn't work either.

What should I so to run my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message appears, because you have never connected with that user account to that host. Therefore the host has no record of this application server host in ssh's `known_hosts` file. Therefore you have to confirm the host before connections can take place.

You can confirm the host by running `ssh someuser@appmachine` from the Linux server where you want to run the application. `appmachine` is the domain name / IP address of the application server your application is connecting to.

Remember to run this `ssh` command as the user that the server software is running as.